# Merge array results from Promise.all & map

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Ok, it's probably a stupid one but it's late and I don't know what my problem is.

I try to get a list of statistics for different type values. The return value in the `map` function is an `Array`. The problem is the end result :

```
// Data
this._types = [{ id: 1, id: 2 }];

// First loop
typeStatistics = [{ name: 'stats a' }, { name: 'stats b' }]

// Second loop
typeStatistics = [{ name: 'stats x' }, { name: 'stats y' }]

// End results (expected)
this._statistics = [
    { name: 'stats a' }, { name: 'stats b' },
    { name: 'stats x' }, { name: 'stats y' }]

// End results I have (wrong)
this._statistics = [
    [ { name: 'stats a' }, { name: 'stats b' } ],
    [ { name: 'stats x' }, { name: 'stats y' } ] ]
```

The code looks like:

```
this._statistics = await Promise.all(this._types.map(async (type) => {
  const typeStatistics = await ApiClientFacade.unwrapResponse(this._api.listTypeStatistics(
    JSON.stringify({ id: type.id }),
  ));

  return typeStatistics;
}));
```

I tried also with `push` and spread operator, with the same results:

```
this._statistics.push(...await Promise.all(this._types.map(async (type) => {
  const typeStatistics = await ApiClientFacade.unwrapResponse(this._api.listTypeStatistics(
    JSON.stringify({ id: type.id }),
  ));

  return typeStatistics;
})));
```

Comment: Is the structure of `this.statistics` an array of arrays and you're trying to flatten them into a single array?

Comment: No, a flat object with properties.

Comment: If it's an object then why are you doing this `this._statistics[0]`? Could share an example structure of what `this.statistics` looks like and what you want it to look like

Comment: Sorry, this.statistics is an array. The typeStatistics return in map is an array. At the end, I want all array typeStatistics merged in this.statistics:
this.statistics[0] = { }
this.statistics[1] = { }
this.statistics[n] = { }

Comment: Perhaps use `.flatMap()` as in `await Promise.all(this._types.flatMap(...))`.

Comment: @Phil I have updated the code.

Comment: Did you try using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) as @jfriend00 suggested?

Comment: Yeah I tried flatMap without success. flat() after work. See solution. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Promise.all` it get all the values of from the api/url and add them into an array. If you want all of them into a single array then you can probably flat the array like below.

```
const data = await Promise.all(this._types.map(async (type) => {
  const typeStatistics = await ApiClientFacade.unwrapResponse(this._api.listTypeStatistics(
    JSON.stringify({ id: type.id }),
  ));

  return typeStatistics;
}));

this._statistics = data.flat();
```

Comment: Gotcha! I've tried to do a flat() at the end of Promise.all().flat() but I got error.

Comment: This might work, but keep in mind that it has a performance challenge cos you're essentially doing some unnecessary loops. [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) in the `Promise.all()` may be a better alternative.

Comment: You can't do it at the end like that cos the `Promise.all()` is still unresolved. Just do it as specified in the answer.

Comment: @fortunee yeah I figure that when I tried it!

Comment: Feel free to accept this as answer if the solution worked for you. :)